# Что означает meta AllowPrivateAccess?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine-4

В одном видео-уроки на YouTube по Unreal C++, парень пишет в редакторе кода:

```
(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "PickupMesh", meta = ( AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
```

Что именно вот это означает **meta AllowPrivateAccess = "true"** и для чего он нужен?

Answer (score 0):

Допустим у вас есть класс Character написанный (С++), у которого есть оружие, которое прописано в графе "private:" таким образом

```
UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadWrite, meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
AWeaponBase* MyWeapon;
```

Так вот, если вы отнаследуете этого перса в BluePrints, вы сможете увидеть это оружие в редакторе блюпринтов, а если убрать AllowPrivateAccess, то оно пропадет от туда